# How to insert values in textbox to select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="" id="ip1" class="ip1" />
<input type="button" value="Add" class="bt1" id="bt1">    
</br>          
<select>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
   $(".bt1").click(function(){
     var opt = $("#ip1").val();
   });
 });
```

Hi friends here i want to add value from text box to select option using jquery,
i got the value from textbox but don't know how to insert, help me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hj5u8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".bt1").click(function(){
        var opt = $("#ip1").val();
        $("select").append('<option value="' + opt+ '">' + opt +'</option>')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

you can do like this:

**HTML:**

```
         <select id="List">
           <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
           <option value="saab">Saab</option>
         </select>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
         $(".bt1").click(function(){

         var opt = $("#ip1").val();

          $('#List')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",opt )
         .text(opt));
         });
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z35r9/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".bt1").click(function () {
        var opt = $("#ip1").val();
        $('select').append(' <option value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>')
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J2QVN/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".bt1").on('click',function () {
    var optionval= $("#ip1").val();
    $('select').append(' <option value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
             $("select").change(function(){

    var opt = $("#ip1").val();
             });
            });
```

Comment: OP does not want to read text box value on change of select box. Please read question once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".bt1").click(function () {
    var opt = $("#ip1").val();
    //check if option already exists in the drop down
    if (!$("select").find("option[value='" + opt + "']").length) {
        //add option to the drop down
        $("select").append("<option value='" + opt + "'>" + opt + "</option>");
    }
    //select entered option
    $("select").find("option[value='" + opt + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LKW89/) here.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var $txtVal = $('#ip1');
    $(".bt1").click(function () {
        var opt = $("#ip1").val();
        if($txtVal.val()){
        $('<option />', { text: $txtVal.val(),value: $txtVal.val()}).appendTo('select');
        }
    });
    });
```

[**FIDDLE HERE >>**](http://jsfiddle.net/prasanthkc/hj5u8/2/)